# .htaccess file ruined my SESSION variables

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, session

I am building a web app with WAMP. I needed to use a .htaccess file so I just created a file in notepad and saved it as .htaccess. From that point, some login session variable were no longer passed to other PHP pages. I decided to delete the .htaccess file entirely, but it did not roll it back.

The current state is that after I start a session via login process, I can't use the session array in other PHP files. Something went wrong. Any ideas?

After every login attempt:

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'core/database/connect.php';
require 'core/functions/clients.php';
$errors = array();

?>
```

calling session vars:

```
<div class="nav_wrapper">
    <div class="container navbar_container ">
        <ul class="navbar">
            <li><a href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="AboutUs.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="products.html">Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="events.html">Events</a></li>
        </ul>

        <?php
        if (isset($_SESSION['email'])) {
            include 'includes/loggedin.php';
            echo $_SESSION['email'];
        } else {
            include 'includes/notloggedin.php';
            echo $_SESSION['email'];
        }

        ?>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's pretty hard to help without any idea what's in your .htaccess and PHP files. And I sincerely doubt you're building a web app with phpMyAdmin. That's a database administration tool, not a programming language or part of another application. Also, are you sure you called `session_start()` in *every* request?

Comment: Of course Im coding php.. I just thought it worth mention it. Anyway, the .htacess included "ן»¿AddType application/x-http-php .css .js" but was deleted. I call session_start in every login, I don't call it in everypage since otherwise I get a "session already started" error.
EDIT: Im pretty noob and its my first project.

Comment: Since you admit you are a n00b, I recommend you move slowly and take things one step at a time. For instance you said ".htaccess included ... but was deleted". This is a very weird thing. I recommend you figure out *how* it got deleted. Also, the line that is missing indicates that your JavaScript and CSS files are to fed to the PHP interpreter (at least that's how I read it). This is also somewhat weird. Where did this idea/code come from?

Comment: Thanks Peter. Firstly by "was deleted" I meant that I deleted the file. Secondly, the content of the htaccess came from instructions of my teachers :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41431440/htaccess-file-ruined-my-session-variables?noredirect=1#comment70068808_41431440), your problem is not in your .htaccess. Your problem is that you are not properly starting and resuming sessions.

You need to call `session_start()` once - and only once - on *every* request, not just during logins. From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php):

> session_start() creates a session *or resumes the current one* based on a session identifier passed via a GET or POST request, or passed via a cookie.

To avoid calling it multiple times, you typically would arrange your application so that you have a "front controller" - a page, often index.php, that handles all requests or at least is included in every request. You would place `session_start()` in that file and only in that file, which ensures it is called once, but prevents it being called more than once during the request.

Comment: Let's say I start a session in Authentication.php which is launched when user is logging in. now in the Home page I want to add "Welcome "username"". Its obviously a different php. can that page use $_SESSION['username'] variable?

Comment: @Johnny yes. Session variables work across PHP files and across requests, *but* you do have to call `session_start()` on every request. Also, you would refer to "a PHP file" or "a PHP script," not "a PHP."

Comment: Thanks Ed. I asked it because thats exactly what I did and it worked (look at my post's code blocks). After I messed with the .htaccess file things have changed. it no longers goes to the loggedin.php script and when I test and echo the $_Session vars I get nothing.

Comment: @Johnny Again, you must call `session_start()` on *every request*, not just on logins. Your posted code *does not* show that you are doing that. That is what is causing your problem.

Comment: Thank you, I understood that I had to start the session each time I want to access its vars. It is working now. I appreciate your help! I also apologize for the misleading post and title.